# Second menu option leads to a crash in Android Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, android-menu

I am creatinga menu for my app. First I only had one menu option (Informationen) and everything worked perfectly fine. Now I want to add a second screen (Impressum). I added the code below, but every time I click on Impressum, my app crashes. The Informationen-screen still works fine.

Has anyone an idea what I am making wrong?

[image]

relevant part of **MainActivity.kt**:

```
override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu?): Boolean {
        val inflater = menuInflater
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu)
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu)
        }

    // actions on click menu items
    override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem) = when (item.itemId) {
        R.id.menu_informationen -> {
            val intent = Intent(this, Info::class.java)
            startActivity(intent)
            true
        }
        R.id.menu_impressumen -> {
            val intent = Intent(this, Impressum::class.java)
            startActivity(intent)
            true
        }
        else -> {
            // If we got here, the user's action was not recognized.
            // Invoke the superclass to handle it.
            super.onOptionsItemSelected(item)
        }

    }
```

**menu_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <item android:id="@+id/menu_informationen"
        android:title="@string/menu_informationen"
        app:showAsAction="never" />
    <item android:id="@+id/menu_impressumen"
        android:title="@string/menu_impressumen"
        app:showAsAction="never" />
</menu>
```

**Impressum.kt**

```
package com.example.servus

import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity

class Impressum : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_impressum)

    }

    override fun onSupportNavigateUp(): Boolean {
        onBackPressed()
        return true
    }
}
```

**activity_impressum.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:paddingRight="10dp"
    tools:context=".Impressum">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/header_info"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/header_info"
        android:textSize="36sp"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif-black"
        android:textColor="#003300"
        />


</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: You should share the stack trace that appears along with the crash.

Comment: Thanks, that actually helped me to solve the problem. I foget to mention the new screen in the manifest.

Comment: I had a feeling that was it but didn't wanna take a wild guess :)

Comment: I was going to say the same about the Manifest. The thing is Android now points out that crash in the log itself. It was difficult to guess previously